# how to show textarea based on select dropdown using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

i want to display 2x dropdown menus both will be pre populated (2nd menu "mainToon" will contain over 200 names but for the example i have shown just a few.

```
<select id="category" name="Category">
    <option value=" "></option>
    <option value=" ">-----------------</option>
    <option value="Main Toon">Main Toon</option>
    <option value="Alt Toon">Alt Toon</option>
    <option value="Cyno Toon">Cyno Toon</option>
    <option value="Super Toon">Super Toon</option>
    <option value="Dust Toon">Dust Toon</option>
</select>

<select id="mainToon" name="mainToon">
    <option value=" "></option>
    <option value=" ">-----------------</option>
    <option value="Agmar">Agmar</option>
    <option value="S Tein">S Tein</option>
    <option value="Karades">Karades</option>
    <option value="Bad Kharma">Bad Kharma</option>
    <option value="Ed jeni">Ed Jeni</option>
</select>
```

by default the first dropdown will show blank and i want the "mainToon" dropdown to be hidden untill any of the following are selected:

"Alt Toon",
"Cyno Toon",
"Super Toon",
"Dust Toon"

Then the form will be visable.

Can i do this by applying a .hidden css code to the dropdown and changing the class dynamically when other options are selected?

many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First hide your dropdown :-

```
<select id="mainToon" name="mainToon" style="display:none;">
</select>
```

And use Jquery show hide function like this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#category").change(function(){
       var value = $(this).val();
        if(value=="Alt Toon" || value=="Cyno Toon")
        {
            $("#mainToon").show();
        }
        else 
        {
           $("#mainToon").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are missing an '=' on `value="Cyno Toon"`, should be `if(value=="Alt Toon" || value=="Cyno Toon")`

Answer (score 1):

Below show the DEMO how to show DIV based on selection value ,

```
    $(function() {
    $('#colorselector').change(function(){
          $('.colors').hide();
          $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
    });
```

And [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/) is working demo.